# Simple sorting function (C++/Processing/Java)

Tags: java, c++, processing

```js
void sort_records_by_id (int []indices, int []students_id )
{
 for (int k = 0; k<indices.length; k++)
 {
  
   for (int j = k; j>0 && indices[j]<indices[j-1]; j--)
   {
    int place holder = indices[j];
    indices[j] = indices [j-1];
    indices[j-1] = place_holder;
   }
 }
}
```

```
void setup()
{ 
  int [] students_id= {10001, 20001, 12334, 14332, 99999, 10111, 20101, 12034, 10332, 99991} ;
  double [] midterm_marks = {99, 67, 88, 91, 56, 90, 70, 69, 79, 59};
  double [] final_marks = {89, 76, 80, 67, 99, 98, 56, 96, 90, 60};
  String [] students_name= {"Tim", "Joe", "Ali", "Kim", "Pam", "Rob", "Ben", "Ted", "Lee", "Jim"};

  print_records(students_id, midterm_marks, final_marks, students_name);

 // Using array of indices to use as an indicator of the order of teh records based on students id numbers   
 int[] indices = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

 // using insertion sort to reorder the indices based on students ids in an ascending order
  sort_records_by_id(indices, students_id);

  println();

  println("The students records after sorting them by their id numbers are as follows:");

  print_sorted_records(indices, students_id, midterm_marks, final_marks, students_name);

  // Searching for the position of a student in the array of names and printing his/her records
  // serarching for "Kim"

  int position = search(students_name, "Kim");

  if(position == -1) {
    println("Search failed: " + "Kim" + " NOT FOUND");
  }
  else {
    double average = calculate_student_average(midterm_marks[position], final_marks[position]);

    println(students_name[position] + " was found: id: " + students_id[position] 
           + " midterm mark: " + midterm_marks[position] + ", final mark: " + final_marks[position] 
           + ", term average: " + average + ", and overal grade: " + letter_grade_calculation (average));  
  }      


  // Searching for "Sam"
  position = search(students_name, "Sam");

    if(position == -1) {
    println("Search failed: " + "Sam" + " NOT FOUND");
  }
    else {
    double average = calculate_student_average(midterm_marks[position], final_marks[position]);

    println(students_name[position] + " was found: id is: " + students_id[position] 
           + " midterm mark: " + midterm_marks[position] + ", final mark: " + final_marks[position] 
           + ", term average: " + average + ", and overal grade: " + letter_grade_calculation (average));  
  }      
}
/*
--------------------------------------------------------------------
The purpose of this function is to calculate the average of all the 
numbers contained in an array and return that value to the calling 
function.

The function REQUIRES
- An array of type double

The function PROMISES
-To return a value of type double to the user
 representing the average of the array passed
 by the user.
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
double calculate_class_average (double [] exam)
{
 int i = 0;
 double sum = 0;

 //iterate through loop and add together the 
 //elements of the array into local variable
 //"sum"
 for (i = 0; i<exam.length; i++)
 {
   sum+=exam[i];
 }
 //Return the value of the average calculated
 //by dividing sum, by the number of times the 
 //loop was executed, representing the # of elements
 return (sum/i);
}

/*
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
The purpose of this function is to calculate the average between
two real numbers passed by the user and return that value to the
calling function

The function REQUIRES:
-Two real numbers of type double

The function PROMISES:
-To return the average between the 
 two values passed by the user as a 
 value of type double
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
double calculate_student_average(double mid_mark, double final_mark)
{
  //Calculate and retrun the average
  //between the two numbers
  return (mid_mark+final_mark)/2;
}

/*
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
The purpose of this function is to return a letter grade to the calling 
function based on the value (grade) passed into the function. 

The function REQUIRES:
-A real number of type double

The function PROMISES:
-To provide a letter grade based on the grade
 provided to the function
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
char letter_grade_calculation(double student_avg)
{
  char ch = ' ';

  //This decision structure compares the value (grade)
  //that was passed into the function to a set of conditions
  //which will assign a letter grade accordingly
  if (student_avg>=90 && student_avg<=100)
  ch = 'A';
  else if (student_avg>=80 && student_avg<=89)
  ch = 'B';
  else if (student_avg>=70 && student_avg<=79)
  ch = 'C';
  else if (student_avg>=60 && student_avg<=69)
  ch = 'D';
  else if (student_avg>=59 && student_avg<=0)
  ch = 'F';

 return ch;
}

/*
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The purpose of this function is to print out the contents of 4 parallel arrays, and other information related to the input, including
the average mark and letter grade. The same index in each array is printed out in one row in the console area. Then 
the content in the following index is printed out for each array in the following row. This is repeated until all of the elements
in each array is printed out. 

This function REQUIRES
- 4 arrays
- An integer array for the first argument
- A array of type double for the second and third argument
- An array of Strings for the fourth and final argument

The function PROMISES
-To print out the contents of each of these arrays in the console area, by printing out the elements in the same index 
in each array for one row, and then printing out each element of the 4 arrays for the following index in the following row.
This is repeated until all of the elements of each array are printed in the console area in this fashion. 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
void print_records(int [] students_id, double []midterm_marks, double []final_marks, String []students_name) 
{
  //Prints the Header for the table once. 
  print("Name \t  id \t  Mid \t Final\t Average \t Mark\n---------------------------------------------------------\n");

  //loop keeps track 
  for ( int i = 0; i<midterm_marks.length; i++)
  {
    double avg = calculate_student_average(midterm_marks[i], final_marks[i]);
    char letter = letter_grade_calculation(avg);
    print(students_name[i],"\t",students_id[i],"\t",midterm_marks[i],"\t",final_marks[i],"\t",avg
          ,"\t",letter, "\n");
  }
}

/*

*/
void sort_records_by_id (int []indices, int []students_id )
{
 for (int k = 0; k<indices.length; k++)
 {

   for (int j = k; j>0 && indices[j]<indices[j-1]; j--)
   {
    int place holder = indices[j];
    indices[j] = indices [j-1];
    indices[j-1] = place_holder;
   }
 }
}

void print_sorted_records(int []index, int [] studnts_id, double []midterm_marks, double []final_marks, String []students_name) 
{
  for(i=0; i<index; i++)
  {
   int k = index[i];
   print(students_name[i],"\t",students_id[i],"\t",midterm_marks[i],"\t",final_marks[i],"\t",avg
          ,"\t",letter, "\n");
  }
}
/*
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The purpose of this function is to search a given array of strings for a particular name or sequence of letters, 
and if it finds the name or sequence of letters, then it returns its index number to the user. If an equivalent entry
in the array is not found, then the function returns a -1 to the calling function.

The function REQUIRES:
-An array of Strings to search through
-A String which is searched for in the array

The function PROMISES:
-To return the index position of the Target word (Word we are searching for)in the
array of strings passed into the function.
-If an equivalent name or sequence of words is not found in the array as the name or sequence
of letters provided by the user, than the function returns -1. 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
int search (String [] students_name, String target)  
{
  //local variable containing the value or index value
  //to be returned to the calling function
  int index =-1 ;

  //This loop iterates through the contents of the array
  //passed into the function, and compares each of its elements
  //to the target/key word the user desires to search for. If a match
  //is successfully found, we overwrite the -1 in the local variable with
  //the index number of the word, and return it to the calling function. Otherwise,
  //if a match is not found, -1 is not overwritten, and that will be the value returned
  //to the user at the end of the loop. 
 for (int k = 0; k<students_name.length; k++)
 {
  //if the String at k in the array matches the target word
  //then we assign k, the counter value, representing index, to 
  //the local variable.
  if(students_name[k].equals(target) == true)
  index = k;
 }
 return index;
}



void sort_records_by_id (int []indices, int []students_id )
{
 for (int k = 0; k<indices.length; k++)
 {

   for (int j = k; j>0 && indices[j]<indices[j-1]; j--)
   {
    int place holder = indices[j];
    indices[j] = indices [j-1];
    indices[j-1] = place_holder;
   }
 }
}
```

I have to create a function that is able to sort an array of integers, not by changing and rearranging its contents, but by changing the order of integers in another array of integers called indexes. 
So, I would have an array with a series of ids such as:
Lets call this id"
    [#] represents index
    [0]10001 
    [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xGRJ.png)2001
    [2]12334
    [3]14332
    [4]999999
    [5]10111

There is a corresponding array, with integer values
    [#] is the index 
Lets call this  arr
    [0]0
    [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xGRJ.png)1
    [2}2
    [3]3
    [4]4
    [5]5
So that they correspond to the indexes we have in the other array.

Now, we must change the order of "arr", such that the elements are in such an order that it corresponds to the order of indexes in array id in sorted order. 
Note, array id is not changed in any way.

So, we can print the ids to the console in ascending order, by using a for loop, the values of arr, and array id.

I hope I was able to explain it sufficiently. I also attached an image to help with clarification. [image]

Basically, my sort function, which can be seen above, does not work as it should.

Comment: I'm not sure you actually asked a question?

Comment: ***I hope I was able to explain it sufficiently.*** You explained you assignment well. You did not explain what your code is doing wrong / what you need help with however.

Comment: sorry about that. I accidentally forgot to include my code. I didn't realize people are so eager to respond within 10 seconds.

Comment: Basically, just to clarify, my sort function which can be seen above is not working as it should be. I'm sure I'm just missing something small.

Comment: ***my sort function which can be seen above is not working as it should be.*** You have to be way more specific than that.

Comment: @MyName You still haven't told us what your question is. Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general questions. It's not really enough to say "this isn't working". Can you please be more specific? What do you expect this code to do? What exactly does this code do instead? Have you narrowed it down to a specific line that's behaving differently from what you expect, using a debugger or print statements?

Comment: @MyName Save yourself a lot of trouble and store the data in a struct (except for the index array).  Then this whole thing becomes a 3 line C++ program, seriously.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how much more info you want. Its a very simple function. I thought my process is correct in the function, but quite simply, I'm not sure how else to put it, but its not working. Its printing out the index array without sorting any of its elements

Comment: @MyName Okay cool, that's a start. What happened when you stepped through this with a debugger, or added some print statements to better understand what's going on? Which line did you find was behaving differently from what you expect?

Comment: Sorry guys. I'm new to all of this. Bear with me.

This function, receives two arrays, one containing the values of the indexes matching the # of indexes in the 2nd array we pass into it. The first array is to be sorted, such that the sorted order corresponds to the sorted order of the second array. however, the second array is not directly edited. that is why the first array representing indexes is sorted. We can then use a for loop and print out the second array in sorted format

Comment: @KevinWorkman I think I should point out that the only code we are focusing on is the sort_records_by_id function. The big block of code is the program as a whole. I thought I would just include it just in case someone wants to piece together more info. 
That being said, there are no errors in the sort_records_by_id function. It just doesn't edit the order of the indexes

Comment: From my understanding, it should be replicating a simple type of sort commonly called Insertion Sort apparently

Comment: So just to emphasize, please just disregard the large block of code. I'll just remove it from the post

Comment: @MyName - [Just for further education, see this](http://ideone.com/SBNRj7)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you for the extra information. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<class I, class C>
void sort_indexes( I begin, I end, C const& container ) {
  using index_type = std::iterator_traits<I>::reference;
  std::sort( begin, end, [&](index_type lhs, index_type rhs) {
    return container[lhs]<container[rhs];
  };
}
```

given an iterator range of indexes (`begin` to `end`) and a container to do lookup, sorts the indexes.

Here we write a generic function.  It takes two iterators `begin` and `end`.  These form a half-open range.  This works like functions in the `<algorithm>` header.

We also take a container.  This container must support lookup using the indexes in our index range with `[]`.  An array, a `std::vector`, even a `std::map` could all work here.

Then we punt.  We get `std::sort` to do the work.  `std::sort` takes 3 arguments.

The first two are iterators (which we have).  The last is a comparison function object.

It must answer the question "given two elements, which is smaller?".  It returns true if the smaller one is on the left.

So we simply do a lookup in the `container` on the indexes!

The rest of the code `template` and the `using` alias is to keep the code generic.  You could write a structurally similar one, with `I` being replaced with `int*`, and `container` being replaced with something you can do a `[]` on, and `index_type` being `int`, easily.

Example use:

```
int indexes[100] = { /* blah */ };
int data[100] = { /* blah */ };

sort_indexes( indexes, indexes+100, data );
```

---

Now in real code, I'd instead write and use `order_by`:

```
template<class F, class O=std::less<>>
auto order_by( F&& f, O&& o = {}) {
  return
    [f = std::forward<F>(f), o = std::forward<O>(o)]
    (auto&& lhs, auto&& rhs)->bool
    {
      return o( f(decltype(lhs)(lhs)), f(decltype(rhs)(rhs)) );
    };
}
```

which is obscure, but we get:

```
std::sort( indexes, indexes+100, order_by( [&](int i){ return data[i]; } ) );
```

ie, the work of `sort_indexes` gets reduced to a call to `order_by` at the call site.

What `order_by` does is it takes a projection from a type T to a type U, then generates an ordering on T based off the mapped-to ordering of U.  This is exactly what you want to do here -- order indexes by values in the table.

---

Here is what all of the above basically generates:

```
void sort_indexes_to_ids( int* begin, int* end, int const* ids ) {
  std::sort( begin, end, [&](int lhs, int rhs) {
    return ids[lhs]<ids[rhs];
  };
}
```

for your concrete case.

---

Using `std::sort` is the right way to solve this problem.  `std::sort` is going to be a more efficient sort than anything you, at your level of skill, are going to write.  Even if you are good enough to beat it in a narrow application, the extra overhead of testing and documenting custom sort code requires justification.

Comment: Please take into account that OP is obviously a beginner. While this is a neat solution, I doubt he will understand much of it. Please consider adding an explanation.

Comment: @paul done!  Complex solutions left in, explained.  Simple solution included.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I truly appreciate it. However, its very difficult for me to convert this program into Processing with my limited knowledge. Is there a simple way to take  my existing function and correct it to make it work?